# Electron + Angular 12 directives don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, electron

I'm developing a web app based on Electron + Angular. The project configurations were fine. In my web app I have four pages, and in some of these (not all pages) I have some not working directives. In particular I have a div container with an *ngIf directive:

```
<div *ngIf="!!configurationFile ">....</div>
```

This is done because the div has to show only when the variable is not empty. The variables are set into the constructor on Subject response:

```
configurationsService.configurationFileContent.subscribe(res => {
        this.configurationFile = res;
    });
```

The configurationFileContent is an RxJS Subject class:

```
configurationFileContent: Subject<ConfigurationFileModelModel> = new Subject<ConfigurationFileModelModel>();
```

and when it's ready it's triggered in this way:

```
this.configurationFileContent.next(JSON.parse(data))
```

I did a lot of tests with a lot of logs into the console end the "configurationFile" variables are not empty, but the div component is still not visible.

I tried a lot of solutions, but none of them worked. The change detections are set to default.

Can it be an electron integration problem and how to solve it?

**Update**

I think it's a zone execution problem because in one of the pages I updated the variable into an ngZone like this:

```
constructor(private electronService: ElectronService,
            private httpClient: HttpClient,
            private comunication: ComunicationBetwenComponentsService,
            private ngzone:NgZone,
            private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.subscription = this.comunication.message.subscribe(res => {
        if (res === 'refresh'){
            ngzone.run(() => {
                this.initializeVariables();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to set the zone to work well without this workaround?